# How to deal with "exception Match raised" while computing relation operators in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I couldn't get the right usage for the relation operator `refl` in Isabelle (2020)'s Main. I assume `refl` on a relation returns true if it's reflexive, same as the `refl_on` example above. But I am still learning these notations.

More specifically:

```
value "refl_on {True,False} {(True,True),(False,False)}"
```

gives `True` as expected. I thought the `refl` is the same, but the following:

```
value "refl {(True,True),(False,False)}"
```

gives an error:

```
exception Match raised (line 39 of "generated code")
```

Other operators such as `sym` seems to be fine:

```
value "sym {(True,True)}"
```

*What is the correct way to use `refl` here?*

-- Update --

There seems to be a similar error with `total`:

```
value "total {(True,True),(False,False)}"
```

, which gives:

```
exception Match raised (line 39 of "generated code")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not expect to be able to evaluate *everything* with `value`. The `value` command is a diagnostic command that is fun to play around with and it can occasionally be useful, but Isabelle/HOL is not a programming language and most HOL terms that you write down cannot be evaluated without additional setup.

The machinery that makes evaluation possible at all is the *code generator*, which translates HOL definitions into executable ML code and then runs that code and converts the result back into HOL terms.

In this case, there is of course no a priori reason why you shouldn't be able to evaluate that term. When things fail, you can either use `export_code` to look at what code is actually generated for your term:

```
definition foo where "foo = refl {(True,True),(False,False)}"

export_code foo in SML
```

Of you can look at the ‘code equations’ used by the code generator

```
definition foo where "foo = refl {(True,True),(False,False)}"

code_thms foo
```

It might be a bit difficult to read, but basically the problem is that sets are, by default, implemented through lists, either as `set xs` (all the elements of the list `xs`) or as `List.coset xs` (all the elements *not* int he list `xs`) and `UNIV` has the code equation `UNIV = List.coset []`. (Note that `refl` is just an abbreviation for `refl_on UNIV`).

Unfortunately, the implementation for `Ball` (the ‘for all elements `x` of the set `x`, `P(x)` holds’ operator) does not know what to do with `List.coset`.

A quick workaround here is to add `(UNIV :: bool set) = {True, False}` as a `code_unfold` rule so that the code generator uses that instead. And with that, it works!

```
lemma UNIV_bool [code_unfold]: "UNIV = {True, False}"
  by auto
```

Comment: Any similar workaround that you may share about `UNIV :: nat set`?

Comment: I'd need some more context. But generally, code generation for anything involving the entire set of natural numbers is unlikely to work except for some trivial cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to see if I could do comparisons with `value` like `UNIV ≠ {2}`, but considering what you say, I probably should change to `nat option` or some other type.

Comment: The problem is that there is no code equation for `List.coset xs ⊆set ys`. This is probably tricky to implement for arbitrary types, although for natural numbers it would, of course, be trivial to do. But as I said, I would just avoid trying to do any computations where you end up using `List.coset`.